# DecodedURL - pass values from html form to the string

Tags: decode, encode, encodeuricomponent, decodeuricomponent

I have a below encoded string that i have to pass as decodeduri in code... it woking fine.... now as a next step... I have pass the dynamic value from my html to dynamicvariable highlighted.

please note...I am enocing and converting to decode is because the content has set of codes that cannot be used in JS as decode directly because of format issue... Thats why i encoding and passing as a decode... now my question is how i can pass variables from html into this encoded string.... please advise..

var dynamicvariable="123";( from html form ), I have to pass to below encoded string now.

Comment: Excuse me... I didnt get your suggestion.... Is that appropriate one?

Comment: ok... can you give a sample working in fiddle...as I couldnt find anythign relavant to your suggestion.